# Display inline-block image link with horizontal scroll

Tags: overflow, css

Trying to display a set of images, inline block with overflow-x to scroll horizontally, but images are not displaying inline, I can't get them to display correctly without floating left.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - I've tried creating set block divs and wrapping around each links and they display inline but as soon as I code them to link, they are no longer inline.  I am using this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/evqt871L/  to check my code and can't figure out why it's not working.

display:

```
<div class="container">
 <a class="seniors" title="Seniors" href="/folio/seniors/">seniors</a>

<a class="equestrian" title="Equestrian" href="/folio/equestrian/">equestrian</a>

<a class="engagement" title="Engagement" href="/folio/engagement/">engagement</a><a class="maternity" title="Maternity" href="/folio/maternity/"> maternity</a><a class="wedding" title="Weddings" href="/folio/weddings/">weddings</a> <a class="family" title="Family" href="/folio/family/">family</a><a class="event" title="Event" href="/folio/event/">event</a>

<a class="professional" title="Professional" href="/folio/professional/">professional</a>
<a class="boudoir" title="Boudoir" href="/folio/boudoir/">boudoir</a>

</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.container{
white-space:nowrap;
overflow-x:auto;
```

}

```
.homepage a.seniors{font-size: 0pt; background: url(images/fp-seniors.png) top center no-repeat; width: 353px; height: 570px; margin: 5px; display: inline-block;}
.homepage a.seniors:hover{text-align: center; height: 320px; padding-top: 250px; font-size: 3em; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none !important; color: #bb4370; opacity: 0.2; -webkit-transition: 3s; -moz-transition: 3s; -o-transition: 3s; -ms-transition: 3s; }
```

Comment: try adding a vertical-align: top to your .box class/or a tags for that matter

Comment: The CSS in your `.homepage a.seniors` declaration fails at the `background` property and discards the rest of the line. When using the shorthand property for background the order of the property values is:
 1 .background-color
 2. background-image
 3. background-repeat
 4. background-attachment
 5. background-position. It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the ones that are present are in this order.

Comment: Thank you, Andrei - will revise!